# Function that returns all numerical values in a string, similar to Val

Tags: vba

Is there a function similar to Val that will give me all the numbers in a string instead of stopping when it reaches a non-numerical character?

For example:

```
Dim myNum As Integer
myNum = Val("24 and 25")
```

'this only gives myNum the value of 24. Is there a function that would set the value to 2425?

Comment: There aren't any inbuilt functions that I am aware of. You could try to parse them out yourself, but unless the strings are standard you may have a difficult time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this custom function

```
Function customVal(s As String) As Long
  With CreateObject("VBScript.Regexp")
    .Pattern = "\D": .Global = True
    customVal = .Replace(s, "")
  End With
End Function
```

---

```
Sub Testing()
  Dim s As String: s = "24 and 25 and 26"
  Debug.Print customVal(s)
End Sub
```

> 242526

Answer (score 1):

Maybe create your own function that uses regular expressions to replace the non-numeric values. Something to the effect of:

```
Dim result As String = Regex.Replace("24 and 25", "[^0-9]", "")
```